# How can I select all elements within a given radius from a point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, geometry

Using [jQuery Nearest Element](https://github.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-nearest), I would like to select elements in a circular area around a specific point.  Here is the closest I can get: http://jsfiddle.net/fuYHv/.  I'd also like to be able to get the inverse selection if possible.  If this is not possible with the plugin and approach I've listed, I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: Im confused. The plugin you linked looks to use the standard distance measure which is radial, `max(distX, distY) : Math.sqrt(distX * distX + distY * distY);`

Comment: @Loktar, perhaps I am not invoking the selection properly? If you take a look at the jsFiddle, it does a rectangular selection.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I made it more SO format friendly.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more precise.  @Erik Philips the intent wasn't to ask for a recommendation, he's included code and everything that SO users usually need to help.

Comment: @Milimetric his original question was.

Comment: fair enough, thank you for the re-consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is proximity:

https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/proximity-event

I got your fiddle working, it turns out the `max: radius` statement doesn't do the intuitive thing, so you have to specifically check the distance for each call on the event.  But it works nicely:

http://jsfiddle.net/fuYHv/12/

```
$(selector + ' span').bind('proximity', {max: radius}, function (event, proximity, distance) {
    $(this).css('color', distance <= radius ? '#f00' : '#000');
});
```

And for a much better and more optimized solution, see the Original Poster's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fuYHv/14/

Comment: I'll take a look into this and report back. Thanks.

Comment: I hate giving such empty responses like this, but... it's not working. Or so it seems. http://jsfiddle.net/fuYHv/2/ Do you see anything I'm doing wrong? (Btw, wouldn't binding it to all 1,000 words cause a huge performance degradation?)

Comment: It's not perfect (have to mess with bad mouse tracks) but I got it to work.  Editing my post now.

Comment: You sir, are a mind reader. You got it to do exactly what I wanted. It's a shame that it's a bit slow.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually amazed it runs at all.  If you come up with any optimizations, be sure to let me know.  This is an awesome way to abuse the web :)

Comment: I optimized it a bit. Instead of adding an event handler to each element, I just went the one event handler route. I also used the plugin I mentioned but filtered the matches that did not fall inside a circle. I also included the each2 plugin which sped it up a good bit. Also, I only modify the elements that need modification when I am changing them back to their normal state. In short, I did just about everything I could to speed it up. Oh, and I also made it into a plugin! AND if that's not enough, I ran it through jslint. Behold! http://jsfiddle.net/fuYHv/14/

Comment: that's awesome.  Good job fellow perfectionist!  :)